# Dynamiclly added audio html in chrome do not play correctly, works in firefox correctly

Tags: javascript, html, audio, dynamic

So I have a js/jquery script that is a type of animation. The animation is bullet holes onto the background. Each hole is to play a bullet sound.

In firefox this works correctly, the waitTime is registered and the bullet sound plays as the canvas is updated. The sound is base64 encoded to reduce loading.

In chrome, I hear maybe 1 or two bullets, or maybe its playing them all at once... How can I fix this for chrome as its the preferred browser for this application.

Example http://hud.zombiebarricades.tv/bulletsounds.html

click the test link to run the animation. 
You should see the bullets holes 'shooting' threw the screen. This is used for as an broadcast overlay to help you understand.

Another issue is during the location generation (watch the console), I see a GET request to undefined, I can't figure out where its coming from.

Comment: There are console messages in Chrome

Comment: Yes but the console states the GET request is from line undefined:1

Answer (score 0):

Chrome seems to have an issue with base64 encoding on audio.

I added the audio tag with base64 as the src and it will not play when displaying inline of a page. Viewing source and click the base64 link inside the src=; chrome opens a new page and plays it correctly.